# Why do I get Nullpointer exception when I create a hibernate mapping XML file?

Tags: java, hibernate-mapping

I am a newbie to hibernate and trying to create a hibernate XML mapping file for a particular class. I am using Spring Tool Suite with hibernate plugin installed and also using Maven. Why do I get the null pointer exception and what could be the reason for it? 
A screenshot is also attached

[image]

It says see error log. But I do not know where the error log exists. I tried a google search too, but could not find a good answer. Any kind of help will be highly appreciated. 
Thank You all !!!!!!

Comment: can you also post the scrrenshot after selecting "Details" ...most likely problem is with your hibernate plugin.

Comment: This is exactly what is in details, "An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
java.lang.NullPointerException". That is all in details

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this problem by using a different version. As said by one of my friends I think the problem was with the version that I was using. Then I tried it with Eclipse Kepler and the problem was gone :)

Answer (score -1):

Set up the hibernate configuration it will be ok 
there is tab called hibernate configuration you add there your projects and you do some configurations there .